# File in /etc/apt/sources.list.d does not show in apt policy, can I delete it?

Tags: apt, directory

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` there are a couple of files that are not listed in `apt policy`. In particular, I'm on 20.04 and the names include `disco` and `eoan`.

Does that mean that they are not used? If so can I just delete those files, as their names do indicate that they are not up-to-date with my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not show in apt policy, you may remove it.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` should only contain files, not directories. If there are directories, you may remove them with no harm as they are ignored by apt.

Filenames in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` must end in `.list` or `.sources`, contain only letters, digit, `-`, `_` and `.`. See [sources.list man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sources.list.5.html) for the details.

Any file with an invalid name can be safely removed since apt ignores that file.

You have to decide to remove or keep a file based on its **content**, not its name; provided the name is a valid name, of course.

If a source list has references to a disco, eon or other version repository, the source will be used.

Under normal circumstances, if the source is a reference to an old ubuntu repository, apt will not download software from this source since it will find newer versions in focal repo. So it is usually harmless to remove those files.

Some vendors may package their product for only one ubuntu version, but the software is known to work with all ubuntu versions. In this case, you should not remove the file.

Comment: Sorry, yes they were files (wasn't looking close enough, used to other `.d` containing directories). Will fix question.

Comment: So if I have both a `eoan` and a `focal`, I can delete the `eoan`? And why are they not listed with `apt policy`?

Comment: yes. you may remove the `eon` one. As for the `apt policy` question, are you sure the filename is valid ?

Comment: Actually the `eoan` had been modified to comment out the line including `eoan` and a line with `focal` added. "disabled on upgrade to focal". So that part was still correct, but it did not show up, which is probably why I had some problems with PHP modules (It was the ondrej/php ppa.) Re-adding the ppa added the new `ondrej-ubuntu-php-focal.list` and now that ppa shows up in `apt policy`.

Comment: Right ! Upgrades modify all the sources and disable all sources that are not pure ubuntu. the added line is the reason why the source was disabled, not an activation of the source. Anyway, you made it ! glad it woks